# Differentiating functions with 2 variables problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

[image]

What I Have:

Let $E=y+lnx$  and   consider $u=x^2f(E)$

Now I'm guessing I have to differentiate it using chain rule somehow

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You have to apply the chain rule to get the partial derivatives.

It is

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2x\cdot f(y+\ln x)+x^2\cdot f'(y+\ln x) \cdot \frac1x=2xf(y+\ln x)+xf'(y+\ln x)$$ and

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0\cdot f(y+\ln x)+x^2\cdot f'(y+\ln x) \cdot 1=x^2f'(y+\ln x).$$  Thus

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2x^2f(y+\ln x)+x^2f'(y+\ln x)-x^2f'(y+\ln x)=2x^2f(y+\ln x)=2u.$$